# Raise matrix to power N as in maths

Tags: python, numpy

In `numpy` if we want to raise a matrix `A` to power `N` (but raise it as defined in mathematics, in linear algebra in particular), then it seems we need to use this function

`numpy.linalg.matrix_power`

Isn't there a simpler way? Some Python symbol/operator?

E.g. I was expecting `A**N` to do this but it doesn't.
Seems that `A**N` is raising each element to power `N`, and not the whole matrix to power `N` (in the usual math sense). So `A**N` is some strange element-wise raising to power `N`.

By matrix I mean of course a two-dimensional `ndarray`.

Comment: I can't reproduce with `np.matrix` (Note: those are deprecated to avoid confusion). If your are using `np.array`: those are not matrices but typed nd-containers. Please provide an input example.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Hm... the `np.matrix` doc says "It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future." So I use a two-dimensional `ndarray`. What is it if not a matrix? Of course mathematically we can think of it as a matrix.

Comment: Technically `ndarrays` are just ctyped, contiguous memory blocks with associated strides.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Well, technically everything in programming is just a sequence of zeros and ones stored somewhere. I am clearly not asking in this context.

Comment: That's not what I meant. There is no collection type in python with those properties. That's the specific definition of what the data structure `np.ndarray` is. The behaviour ("like a matrix" or "like an iterator over the memory block") is defined by functions, not by the data structure. This separation was made deliberately.

Comment: With `numpy` most operators work element-wise.  `matmul/@` is a recent notable exception, and even that has an element-wise behavior in the higher dimensions.  `np.matrix` is a subclass designed to be more MATLAB like, redefining the use of * and **.

Comment: Operators are converted by the interpreter into method calls.  Those class specific methods define the action.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: x=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
```

For this square array:

```
In [6]: np.linalg.matrix_power(x,3)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 6, 11],
       [22, 39]])

In [7]: x@x@x
Out[7]: 
array([[ 6, 11],
       [22, 39]])
```

`matrix_power` is written in python so you can easily read it.  It essentially does a sequence of `dot` products, with some refinements to reduce the steps.

For `np.matrix` subclass, `**` does the same thing:

```
In [8]: mx=np.matrix(x)
In [9]: mx**3
Out[9]: 
matrix([[ 6, 11],
        [22, 39]])
```

`**` is translated by the interpreter to a `__pow__` call.  For this class that just amounts to a `matrix_power` call:

```
In [10]: mx.__pow__??
Signature: mx.__pow__(other)
Docstring: Return pow(self, value, mod).
Source:   
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return matrix_power(self, other)
File:      c:\users\paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py
Type:      method
```

But for `ndarray` this method is a compiled one:

```
In [3]: x.__pow__??
Signature:      x.__pow__(value, mod=None, /)
Call signature: x.__pow__(*args, **kwargs)
Type:           method-wrapper
String form:    <method-wrapper '__pow__' of numpy.ndarray object at 0x0000022A8B2B5ED0>
Docstring:      Return pow(self, value, mod).
```

`numpy` does not alter python syntax.  It has not added any operators.  The `@` operator was added to python several years ago, largely as a convenience for packages like `numpy`.  But it had to added to the interpreter's syntax first.

Note that `matrix_power` works for a

```
a : (..., M, M) array_like
     Matrix to be "powered".
```

That means it has to have at least 2 dimensions, and the trailing two must be equal size.  So even that extends the normal linear algebra definition (which is limited to 2d).

`numpy` isn't just a linear algebra package.  It's meant to be a general purpose array tool.  Linear algebra is just a subset of math that can be performed with multidimensional collections of numbers (and other objects).

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.linalg.matrix_power` is the best way as far as I know. You could use `dot` or `*` in a loop, but that would just be more code, and probably less efficient.